# How to select people that have purchased only 1 items in a year using Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel question

In any given year, students book 1 or more courses. I would like to select from this list just those students that have only bought 1 course, only bought 2 courses and bought 3 courses or more.

Here's a very simplified version of the excel doc:

[Students and courses table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHxaw.jpg)

I have tried =COUNTIFS(D:D, D2,A:A, Registered)=1 but they all returned false

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated

Comment: So how many points do we get for doing your homework? :) Have you researched anything yet? What have you tried and how did that not work?

Comment: full points :) I have tried =COUNTIFS(D:D, D2,A:A, Registered)=1 but they all returned false

Comment: Ok, please add that to your question to make in on topic at least.

Comment: added that - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need add double quotes in the formula to get the expected result..

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,A:A, "Registered")
```

[image]

Also you can use [Pivot Table](https://exceljet.net/excel-pivot-tables)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - I just missed a little bit after all. That's solved it